# Vbscript logging into ftp

Tags: vbscript

I am attempting to log into ftp host and download files.  I am not sure how to locate the file as it is stored in directories under the date and will change every day. this is what I have so far

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO, objMyFile, objShell, strFTPScriptFileName, strFilePut
Dim strLocalFolderName, strFTPServerName, strLoginID
Dim strPassword, strFTPServerFolder


strLocalFolderName = "c:\foldername"
strFTPServerName = "ftp.host.com"
strLoginID = "somelogin"
strPassword = "password8"
```

so after the password how would I log into the date file and locate so for example the file would be under

20130722/filename.ftp

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here. Are you asking how to create a folder name from the current date? Or are you asking how to identify a particular file in a folder on an FTP server? By what distinguishing features?

Comment: Hi, I need to identify the file in the folder. they are stored in folders named by date then a file is stored in that folder.  so the folder would be 20130722 then the ftp file is in that folder. so when I log in manually I change directory cd 20130722 then get file.ftp

Comment: Again, how do you identify that file? Do you know the name? Is it the only file in the folder? Does it have any other distinguishing features?

Comment: Ok sorry. Yes it is in a directory named by date the the files are cs.ftp cx.ftp ri.ftp and ug.ftp

Comment: so today the files would be 20130722/cs.ftp  then I need data in that file.

Comment: I am not sure how I would log into the file if the directory changes name every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to do this in VBScript is to generate an FTP script and run that with `ftp.exe`:

```
'variable definitions
...

Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

remoteDir = Year(Date) & Right("0" & Month(Date), 2) & Right("0" & Day(Date), 2)
tempDir   = sh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
script    = fso.BuildPath(tempDir, "download.ftp")
logfile   = fso.BuildPath(tempDir, "ftp.log")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(script, 2, True)
f.WriteLine "open" & strFTPServerName & vbNewLine _
  & "user" & strLoginID & vbNewLine _
  & strPassword & vbNewLine _
  & "prompt no" & vbNewLine _
  & "lcd " & strLocalFolderName & vbNewLine _
  & "cd " & remoteDir & vbNewLine _
  & "get cs.ftp" & vbNewLine _
  & "bye"
f.Close

rc=sh.Run("%COMSPEC% /c ftp -s:" & qq(script) & " >" & qq(logfile), 0, True)

WScript.Echo "FTP finished with exit code " & rc & "."

fso.DeleteFile script, True
```

The above should work out of the box. If you're free to install additional software, the FTP client included with [ActiveXperts' Network Component](http://www.activexperts.com/activsocket/howto/ftp/vbscript/) might be another option.